# jQuery dynamic canvas creation, $ctx.getContext is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

When I try to execute this in jQuery I get `$ctx.getContext is not a function` in firebug.

```
var $ctx = $( '<canvas />', {width:'100', height:'100'} )
$widget.append($ctx)                                     
$ctx.getContext('2d')
```

Any idea why I get this error? How do I dynamically create and initialize a canvas element?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`$ctx` is a jQuery object. use `$ctx[0].getContext('2d')` to get the context

Comment: `var $ctx = $( '<canvas />', {width:'100', height:'100'} )[0].getContext('2d')`

Comment: that would assign $ctx the canvas context which is both confusing and not, I believe, what Evan is going for... he does need to collect the result of the getContext() call tho - so you're correct there...

Comment: @Evan, you jumped the append step now .. for a single liner try `$( '<canvas />', {width:'100', height:'100'} ).appendTo($widget)[0].getContext('2d')` but now you do not have a variable that is referencing your jquery object..

Comment: @scott, it is Evan that posted the comment ;)

Comment: @EvanCarroll - You might want to consider accepting this answer (even though it's two years old)

Answer (score 2):

If using excanvas you will need to use the following so it works in IE.

```
var canvas = $ctx[0];

if (canvas.getContext == undefined) {
    return G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas).getContext("2d"); 
}

return canvas.getContext('2d')
```

Answer (score -6):

first thing first , you need to check out if the following line is exist and the top of HTML document.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN">
```

this line as a browser render policy excuted condition.

Comment: How is this related to the question?