# jQuery selectors giving inconsistent behavior

Tags: jquery, canvas

Can anyone explain the following behavior?

```
var ctx = $('#myCanvas').getContext("2d");      //doesnt work 
var ctx = $('#myCanvas')[0].getContext("2d");   //works
canvasWidth = $('#myCanvas').width();           //works
canvasHeight = $('#myCanvas').height();         //works
canvasWidth = $('#myCanvas')[0].width();        //doesnt work
canvasHeight = $('#myCanvas')[0].height();      //doesnt work
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$('#myCanvas')` is a [jQuery object](http://docs.jquery.com/Types#jQuery). `$('#myCanvas')[0]` is a [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element).

[width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) are methods exposed by jQuery objects. You cannot call them on DOM elements, because they do not implement them (so far).

Likewise, [getContext()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement) is a method exposed by the `<canvas>` DOM element, and jQuery objects do not support it.

Comment: To elaborate, getContext() is a DOM method while width() and height() are jQuery methods.

Comment: In your JS console run `console.dir($('#myCanvas'));` and you can see what these guys are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

`$('#myCanvas')` returns the a jquery object while `$('#myCanvas')[0]` returns the HTML/DOM element.

---

In a similar way, `$(selector).eq(0)` returns first item in the list as a jquery object while `$(selector).get(0)` returns the HTML/DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

getContext is not a jquery function, it is an element function.  width and height are jquery functions which are called on a jQuery object.

Also see: [jQuery dynamic canvas creation, $ctx.getContext is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239680/jquery-dynamic-canvas-creation-ctx-getcontext-is-not-a-function)